# How to save the result of a button's command in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

def get_pass():

    user_password = simpledialog.askstring("Password Entry", "Enter your password here:")
    return user_password

submitButton = tk.Button(content, text="Start", command=get_pass)

#now I want to work with the password that the user entered.
```

The user is supposed to click the 'start' button. Upon clicking the button, a tkinter messagebox shows up which asks the user to enter their password. The user enters their password and submits it. According to the code above, the password is returned as a string named user_password.

The question is, how can I use what the user entered? The button doesn't save the return value of functions.

Comment: `command=` can't retrieve result of `get_pass()` so use `global` variable to assign `user_password`.

Comment: @furas thank you, that makes sense. I'm a beginner, so I would be grateful is you showed me how to set a variable as a global variable so I could use it outside of that function.

Comment: see my answer and comments in code

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add `submitButton.pack()` or `submitButton.grid()` to display the button in the tk window. Returning the user_password doesn't work because you're not assigning 'command' to the password. You can change your function to something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

def get_pass():
    global user_password
    user_password = simpledialog.askstring("Password Entry", "Enter your password here:")
    content.destroy()

content=tk.Tk()
submitButton = tk.Button(content, text="Start", command=get_pass)
submitButton.config(height=6, width=25, fg='red') #looks a little nicer
submitButton.pack()
content.mainloop()

#Do stuff with user_password
#print(user_password)
```

when you print user_password later on it will show the password entered though the simpledialog. The password is user_password now.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. When I write print(user_password) after running the function, pycharm says "NameError: name 'user_password' is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

`command=` can't receive value returned from `get_pass()` so you can use `global` variable (or `StringVar`) to assign `user_password`. Or use this value directly in `get_pass()` to check password and you will no have to return it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

def get_pass():
    # inform function to use external/global variable when you use `=`
    global user_password

    # `user_password_var` is global variable too
    # but it doesn't need `global user_password_var` 
    # because it doesn't need `=` to assign value.

    result = simpledialog.askstring("Password Entry", "Enter your password here:")

    user_password = result
    # or
    user_password_var.set(result)
    # or
    if result != '123456':
        label['text'] = "ERROR: password is incorrect"
    else:
        label['text'] = "password is OK"

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# it creates global variable 
user_password = ''
# or
user_password_var = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

submitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=get_pass)
submitButton.pack()

# both variables are empty before `mainloop`

root.mainloop()

# both variables have value after `mainloop`

# print after you exit program
print(user_password)
print(user_password_var.get())
```

Comment: Does that mean that the value that the user entered becomes available to print only after I close the window? Isn't there a  way to print the value as soon as the user presses 'submit'?

Comment: No, it only means that `mainloop` starts program and it executes `get_pass()` when you click button. Before `mainloop` window doesn't exist yet.

Comment: you can print value inside `get_pass()` but this function is not executed before `mainloop()` but inside `mianloop()`